# ASP.NET Web Application gives HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error.

Tags: iis-7

I have hosted a WEB Api application in local and on "Browse" i am getting below error. Pals, Please help on it.

Error Summary 
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error

Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

Detailed Error Information

Module
IIS Web Core

Notification
ExecuteRequestHandler

Handler
ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0

Error Code
0x8007000d

Requested URL
http://localhost:8082/

Physical Path
D:\WEB API Publish

Logon Method
Anonymous

Logon User
Anonymous

Most likely causes: •Managed handler is used; however, ASP.NET is not installed or is not installed completely.
•There is a typographical error in the configuration for the handler module list.

Things you can try: •Install ASP.NET if you are using managed handler.
•Ensure that the handler module's name is specified correctly. Module names are case-sensitive and use the format modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule".

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error when .NET 4.5 was installed but not under the IIS role. Try following these steps:

1. Open Server Manager -> Add Roles and Features.
2. Click next until you get to the “Server Roles” page.
3. Scroll down to “Web Server (IIS)” and expand it.
4. Expand Web server -> expand Application Development.
5. Check the option for ASP.NET 4.5 and hit yes to the additional components pop-up.